# how to apply auto complete for dynamically created input box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, autocomplete

I have 5 input box to add product,if user want to add more product he can click on add more product and 5 new dynamically created text box will appear.My problem is i am not  able to give auto complete to my Dynamic input box but not able to give auto complete to my static  input box.

My HTML CODE

```
<div class="pro" id="dynamicInput">
<div>Product Name 1
<input style="border:2px solid #7f9db9" name="product_1" id="in_pc_item_moq_unit_type1" class="ui-autocomplete-input" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter your product name" type="text" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
<input type="hidden" id="in_pc_item_moq_1">
</div>
<div>Product Name 2

<input style="border:2px solid #7f9db9" name="product_2" id="in_pc_item_moq_unit_type2" class="ui-autocomplete-input" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter your product name" type="text" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
</div>
<div>Product Name 3
<input style="border:2px solid #7f9db9" class="ui-autocomplete-input" id="in_pc_item_moq_unit_type3" maxlength="100" name="product_3" placeholder="Enter your product name" type="text" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
</div>
<div>Product Name 4

   <input style="border:2px solid #7f9db9" class="ui-autocomplete-input" id="in_pc_item_moq_unit_type4" maxlength="100" name="product_4" placeholder="Enter your product name" type="text" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
</div>
 <div>Product Name 5

   <input style="border:2px solid #7f9db9" class="ui-autocomplete-input" id="in_pc_item_moq_unit_type5" maxlength="100" name="product_5" placeholder="Enter your product name" type="text" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
 </div>
            </div>
<div class="ta m15">
    <input name="gluserid" id="glid" value="7171786" type="hidden">     <input type="button" value="Add more product"  onclick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
     <input type="submit" value="submit"  name="submit">


        </div>
```

My java script code for dynamically add inputbox is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var counter = 1;
        var limit = 4;
        var num=6;
function addInput(divName){
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     }
     else {
         for(var i=1;i<=5;i++)
         {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "Product Name " + (num) + "<input style='border:2px solid #7f9db9'  class='ui-autocomplete-input' id='in_pc_item_moq_unit_type" + num + "' maxlength='100' type='text' name='product_" + num + "' placeholder='Enter your product name'>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          num++
      }
    counter++;
     }
}

    </script>
```

My script for auto suggest is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function auto_suggest(id)
    {
        if(typeof(Suggester)!="undefined")
        {
            sugg=new Suggester({"element":id,"onSelect":selecttext,"type":"mcat","placeholder":"Enter your product name","classPlaceholder":"ui-placeholder-input",minStringLengthToFetchSuggestion:1});
        }else
        {
            setTimeout(function(){
            auto_suggest()},50);
        }
    }
        auto_suggest('in_pc_item_moq_unit_type1');
        auto_suggest('in_pc_item_moq_unit_type2');
        auto_suggest('in_pc_item_moq_unit_type3');
        auto_suggest('in_pc_item_moq_unit_type4');
        auto_suggest('in_pc_item_moq_unit_type5');
        auto_suggest('in_pc_item_moq_unit_type6');
        auto_suggest('in_pc_item_moq_unit_type7');
        auto_suggest('in_pc_item_moq_unit_type8');
        auto_suggest('in_pc_item_moq_unit_type9');
        auto_suggest('in_pc_item_moq_unit_type10');
        auto_suggest('in_pc_item_moq_unit_type11');
        auto_suggest('in_pc_item_moq_unit_type12');
        auto_suggest('in_pc_item_moq_unit_type13');
        auto_suggest('in_pc_item_moq_unit_type14');
        auto_suggest('in_pc_item_moq_unit_type15');
        auto_suggest('in_pc_item_moq_unit_type16');
        auto_suggest('in_pc_item_moq_unit_type17');
        auto_suggest('in_pc_item_moq_unit_type18');
        auto_suggest('in_pc_item_moq_unit_type19');
        auto_suggest('in_pc_item_moq_unit_type20');



    function selecttext(event, ui)
    {
        this.value = ui.item.value;



    }

</script>
```

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(var i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
   var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
   newdiv.innerHTML = "Product Name " + (num) + "<input style='border:2px solid #7f9db9'  class='ui-autocomplete-input' id='in_pc_item_moq_unit_type" + num + "' maxlength='100' type='text' name='product_" + num + "' placeholder='Enter your product name'>";
   document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
   num++;
   auto_suggest('in_pc_item_moq_unit_type' + num); // apply autocomplete after element creation
}
```

Comment: try: auto_suggest('in_pc_item_moq_unit_type' + num);  I hope this will work

Comment: Any  other suggestion